# SwiftUI segmented picker default state as nil

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

I'm using a segmented picker in a form to answer simple "Yes" and "No" questions. Can the segmented picker initial state be set to nil so that neither yes or no is highlighted/selected on appear?

```
@State private var equipmentCheck = 0
private var answers = ["Yes", "No"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Questions")) {
                Text("Have the plant and equipment been checked?")
                Picker("", selection: $equipmentCheck) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< answers.count, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\(self.answers[$0])")
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with `SwiftUI` but as I see you are setting picker's label by yourself. why not customise the `Text` in `ForEach` block according to `equipmentCheck `. Now here you have to keep in your mind that this `Picker` have three stats now - `none, yes , no`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you set the selected value to an index that is not in your segmented control, then none of the values are highlighted.

For example:

```
@State private var equipmentCheck = -1
```

works.

I’m looking for documentation that confirms that this is guaranteed to work, but have found none.

The documentation for [`selectedSegmentIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618575-selectedsegmentindex) of UIKit’s `UISegmentedControl` says to set the value to -1 to remove the selection, so it seems reasonable to do so here as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible approach. Tested & worked with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
@State private var equipmentCheck: Int?        // << here !!
private var answers = ["Yes", "No"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Questions")) {
                Text("Have the plant and equipment been checked?")
                Picker("", selection: $equipmentCheck) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< answers.count, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\(self.answers[$0])")
                           .tag(Optional($0))           // << here !!
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to rely on the same mechanism that a selection that matches no tag will show an unselected interface. Do you know of any documentation that specifies that this is official behavior?